why am I getting Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './build/Debug/farmhash.node error during my firebase setup in Node.js
I am writing some server side code in my angular application.
For that I need firbase-admin. I am following the steps from the official website here
for firebase-admin installation. After that I wrote


import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

async function authenticateWithFirebase(email: string, password: string) {
  // Authenticate with Firebase Admin SDK
  const user = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email);

  // Generate a custom token for the authenticated user
  const token = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(user.uid);

  return token;
}



Once I write this and compile I start getting the following error
    ./node_modules/farmhash/index.js:7:11-49 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './build/Debug/farmhash.node' in 'E:\workspace\app-frontend\node_modules\farmhash'

./node_modules/farmhash/build/Release/farmhash.node:1:2 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)


I am still not able to know why this is happening and how to deal with this. Please help
FYI i am using Angular CLI: 16.2.1 and
Node: 18.18.2

On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Also make sure your firebase-admin is at the lastest version.  If it is, you should post an issue on the firebase-admin GitHub because farmhash has been a known problem lately.

I got a similar error in my Next.js app. "next": "^14.2.3", "firebase-admin": "^12.1.0", when I try to call verifySessionCookie
Failed to compile
Next.js (14.2.3) ./node_modules/farmhash/build/Release/farmhash.node Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders (Source code omitted for this binary file). 

I downgraded to firebase-admin 12.0.0 as some people on github suggested and now I get the following error:
Error: The edge runtime does not support Node.js 'os' module. Learn More: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/node-module-in-edge-runtime
So this error message does make more sense to me.

Also running into this issue with Firebase Admin on NextJS. Anyone find a solution to this?
